# Function with constant reference as input

Tags: c++, string, reference

I am trying to make a function that takes a constant reference of a string as input and returns the string after each character of the string is rotated 1 place to the right. Using references and pointers still confuses me and I am not sure how to obtain the string from the constant reference.

```
string rotate(const string &str){
     string *uno =  &str;
     string dos = rotate(uno.rbegin(), uno.rbegin() + 1, uno.rend());
     return dos;}
```

This is what I have got so far but it does not compile. Any tips on how to properly get the string from the constant reference will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't perform the rotation in-place without violating the `const` contract on the parameter, so you should copy the input and return a new string:

```
string rotate(const string &str){
     string uno = str;
     rotate(uno.rbegin(), uno.rbegin() + 1, uno.rend());
     return uno;
}
```

Another reasonable option would be to use [`std::rotate_copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate_copy)

Comment: This did not compile for me.

Comment: /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 1 has invalid symbol index 12
it goes on and on like that for for about 40 lines.

Comment: Well it works for me: http://rextester.com/KTX13472  Looks like this code is not the source of your compile error.

Comment: @user3699546, From my Coliru experiences, you're missing a `main` when you get that.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
string* uno = string &str;
```

makes no sense. I think you mean

```
string* uno = const_cast<string*>(&str);
```

Comment: Except that this would cause a compiler error due to trying to get rid of `const`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Check revision 1.

Comment: The cast isn't doing any better. If the user passes in an actual constant string, it will be modified by `std::rotate`.

Comment: This is a dangerous solution breaking the function's contract.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider this rotate:

```
// rotate last char to front
std::string rotate(const std::string& str)
{
   return(str[str.size()-1]  + 
          str.substr(0,str.size()-1));
}

// 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
// 'zabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pass in a string to receive the rotated string, thus avoiding return by value copy.

I passed the string in by pointer, as its clearer at the call site that it's intended to be altered, but it could easily be passed by reference if preferred.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

void rotate(std::string const& str, std::string* out)
{
     *out = str;
     std::rotate(out->rbegin(), out->rbegin() + 1, out->rend());
}

int main(int, char**)
{
    std::string out;

    std::string x = "1234567";
    std::cout << x << '\n';

    ::rotate(x, &out);

    std::cout << out << '\n';
}
```